# In the graph, why 'z' is not considered?

Tags: graphing-functions

https://www.geogebra.org/m/dv86k7uy

The graph shows error when you visit the above site.
But if you click the "undefined" text twice and click somewhere else, the graph gets plotted.
Question is: why the graph has no '$z$' points plotted?

Explanation of the question:
The graph $1=xyz$ should have $z$ that looks like this: https://www.geogebra.org/3d/n5m2jjx7 (example $xz = 1$) but in the graph $1 = xyz$ the $'z'$ points are not considered?

Comment: That's related to how WA was designed, not related to math. However, in this case you can isolate $z$ to obtain $z=1/xy$, and this can be drawn by WA. Don't forget to graph $xy=0$ apart!

Comment: What is WA? What happens when I graph xy=0?

Comment: WA is commonly used as a shortcut of Wolfram Alpha. Forget about the $xy=0$, I messed up.

Answer (score 0):

Implicit 3D plot are not yet implemented in GeoGebra.

You must enter $z=\frac{1}{xy}$.